# Java println formatting so I can display a table?

Tags: java, command-line

How can I utilize `System.out.print(ln/f)` in a way that will allow me to format my output into a table?

If I'm to use `printf`, what formatting should I specify to achieve the below results?

Example table I'd like to print:

```
n       result1      result2      time1      time2    
-----------------------------------------------------  
 5      1000.00      20000.0      1000ms     1250ms
 5      1000.00      20000.0      1000ms     1250ms
 5      1000.00      20000.0      1000ms     1250ms
```

With everything lined up nice and pretty?

Comment: I'm not doing homework and I found this question useful

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, since Java 5, the `PrintStream` class used for `System.out` has the [`printf`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method, so that you can use [string formatting.](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

---

*Update:*

The actual formatting commands depend on the data you are printing, the exact spacing you want, etc. Here's one of many possible examples:

```
System.out.printf("%1s  %-7s   %-7s   %-6s   %-6s%n", "n", "result1", "result2", "time1", "time2");
System.out.printf("%1d  %7.2f   %7.1f   %4dms   %4dms%n", 5, 1000F, 20000F, 1000, 1250);
System.out.printf("%1d  %7.2f   %7.1f   %4dms   %4dms%n", 6, 300F, 700F, 200, 950);
```

Comment: What do I put in printf to make table headings?

Comment: You write it as you want to view it. printf() isn't a table maker.

Answer (score 4):

you can `println("\t")` which prints a tab, it will align everything easily.

Comment: Not if the values have different lengths.

Comment: While `\t` isn't perfect, many terminals will format tabs as a variable-spaced element, letting you easily align similar data into columns.  Even better, spreadsheet programs like Excel can easily parse tab-separated data (TSV) - personally, I find the format more readable and easier to work with than the more common comma-separated (CSV).