# How to format multiple Strings so that they are flush with each other

Tags: swift, nsstring

## Description

I want to format multiple strings so that they are flush with each other. (See actual result and expected result)

## what i tried

I have implemented this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31613297/11582550
(See code)
It also works, but only if I print the result in the console. I want to save the text in label.text, that doesn't work.

## some code

```swift
func formattedString(left:String, right:String) -> String {
        let left = (left as NSString).utf8String
        let right = (right as NSString).utf8String
        print(String(format:"%-20s %-20s", left!, right!))
        return String(format:"%-20s %-20s", left!, right!)
    }

label.text += formattedString(left: "Firstname: ", right: "Alfred") + "\n" + formattedString(left:"Lastname: ", right: "LongLastname") + "\n" + formattedString(left:"Note:", right: "private")

// actual result
```

## what i expected

```
## actual result (saved in label.text)
Firstname:    Alfred
Lastname:    LongLastname
Note:    private

## expected result (saved in label.text)
Firstname:    Alfred
Lastname:     LongLastname
Note:         private
```

Comment: It's unclear, expected result & actual result seems to be the same.

Comment: So your problem is that the columns do not align because the font is a proportional font, where different characters can have different width?

Comment: @vacawama: Thanks for editing -- that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: I think @MartinR identified your problem in his first comment.  Choose a fixed space font (such as Courier New) for your label and that should solve your issue.

Comment: @Martin R and vacawama:  actually, that solved my problem. Thank you! I will mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using a proportional font instead of a fixed-width font for your label.  In proportional fonts, the character widths vary, so you can't expect the characters to align.

Change the font that your label is using to a fixed-width font (such as *Courier*, *Courier New*, or *Menlo*) and that will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using low-level C functions and C strings (pointer) in Swift, I suggest using pure Swift string manipulation:

```
func formattedString(left: String, right: String, width: Int = 20) -> String {
    // The `max` call returns 0 if `width - left.count` is negative
    let filler = String(repeating: " ", count: max(0, width - left.count))
    return left + filler + right
}

let result = formattedString(left: "Firstname: ", right: "Alfred") + "\n" + formattedString(left:"Lastname: ", right: "LongLastname") + "\n" + formattedString(left:"Note:", right: "private")
print(result)

// Firstname:          Alfred
// Lastname:           LongLastname
// Note:               private
```

To cut off long strings, you could do it like this:

```
func limit(string: String, length: Int) -> String {
    if string.count <= length {
        return string
    }
    return string.prefix(length) + "…"
}
```

Comment: This solves my question, but opens up the next problem with longer inputs that cause a line break.