# Create evenly spaced numbers in a table

Tags: java

I have used `TreeMaps` to calculate the frequencies of letters in user-entered text. When displaying these frequencies I get quite a messy output as some frequencies are zero, and others are numbers to one or two decimal places.

An example, from entering `Harry`:

```
Letter |a |b |c |d |e |f |g |h |i |j |k |l |m |n |o |p |q |r |s |t |u |v |w |x |y |z |
Count  |0.2 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0.2 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0.4 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0.2 |0 |
```

How do I produce a table which is neatly spaced (and without knowing the frequencies), like this:

```
Letter |a   |b |c |d |e |f |g |h   |i |j |k |l |m |n |o |p |q |r   |s |t |u |v |w |x |y   |z |
Count  |0.2 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0.2 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0.4 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0 |0.2 |0 |
```

To produce my table I have used simple `for` loops which increment through the `Treemap`, and I was thinking of the `System.out.format` command, but I'm still learning a lot about `java` so this would probably be wrong.

My for loops are here:

```
System.out.print("Letter |");
for (char a: Allmap.keySet()) {
  System.out.print(a + " |");
}

System.out.print("\n" + "Count  |");
for (double b: Allmap.values()) {
  System.out.print(df.format(b / CHARCOUNT) + " |");
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind that, printing all the numbers with the same number of digits is the simplest way to do it (0.00, 0.20, 0.37, etc.). Otherwise you should check, before printing the letter, the number of digits used by the number.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745206/3182664 (also see the "Linked" answers/questions), and I recently created a utility class for that http://stackoverflow.com/a/29054406/3182664

Comment: @Marco13 Thank you for the helpful links. May I ask why you downvoted the question?

Comment: @HarryJones I did not vote. (I rarely vote at all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like this, although I haven't had time to test it.

```
System.out.print("Letter |");
for (char a : Allmap.keySet()) {
    System.out.print(a + " |");
}

System.out.print("\nCount  |");
for (double b : Allmap.values()) {
    System.out.printf( "%.2f |", d );
}
```

Also note that this code will round the `double` to two decimal places, so `3.14159` becomes `3.14`, and `2.71828` becomes `2.72`.

Also, here was my source for rounding a `double` to two decimal places:
[Round a double to 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808535/round-a-double-to-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Remember to click the tick of the best answer to your question. The tick is just below the upvote/downvote arrows.

Comment: Yes sorry, Thank you that helps a lot :) @GeorgeEpicGen