# alignment of table in array java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

My code is this:

```
// for loop for displaying multiple values
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) { 

    System.out.println("\t\t" + name[index] + "\t\t\t" + "$" + sales[index] + "\t\t\t" + "$" + comm[index] + " ");
}
```

This is the current output, but I want to display output with same spacing

```
             Sales and Commission
    ======================================================
     Salesperson        Sales Amount        Commission
    -----------------------------------------------------
    u ujuhygtfd         $89000          $8900.0 
    uh uh           $87000          $8700.0 
    t t         $65000          $5200.0 
    f f         $54000          $4320.0 
    u r         $43000          $2580.0 

     Total: 9 Data entries
```

How can I display my data like this?

```
             Sales and Commission
    ======================================================
     Salesperson        Sales Amount        Commission
    -----------------------------------------------------
    u ujuhygtfd         $89000          $8900.0 
    uh uh               $87000          $8700.0 
    t t                 $65000          $5200.0 
    f f                 $54000          $4320.0 
    u r                 $43000          $2580.0 

     Total: 9 Data entries
```

Comment: It usually is helpful to add a language tag.  I assume java in this case?

Comment: I don't if there is a better way (probably there is), but you can test on the size of your strings, for example all the `Salesperson`'s `strings` must be 10 characters long, so if your string is only 4 you'll add 6 `spaces`

Comment: @njzk2: sure, but is it an exact duplicate? see also http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: Instead use some GUI components from Swing/AWT, if redirecting the output to the I/O console is supplementary.

Comment: @user1587329: In this case, I am fairly confident that the information contained in the duplicate candidate is largely sufficient and there is no need for anything else (apart from may be writing their complete program for the OP, but that's beyond the scope, i should say)

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29054406/3182664

Answer (score 2):

As said [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745239/1587329) (slightly modified):

> Use [System.out.format](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29). You can set lengths of fields like this:
>
> `System.out.format("%32s%10d%16d", name[index], sales[index], comm[index]);`
>
> This pads `name[index]`, `sales[index]`, and `comm[index]` to 32, 10, and 16 characters,
>   respectively.
>
> See the Javadocs for [java.util.Formatter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for more information on the
>   syntax (`System.out.format` uses a `Formatter` internally).

Comment: An additional benefit of formatted Strings is they are easier to read usually. `("Name: " + name + "Commission: " + amount)` versus `("Name: %s Commission: %d", name, amount)` and it's hard to shoot yourself in the foot and forget a space, the first String in my example could read `"Name: CaptainManCommission: 100"`, it's hard to immediately tell though.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) { // for loop for displaying multiple values
        int numOfSpaces = 20 - name[index].length();
        String spaces = "";
        for (int i = 0; i<numOfSpaces; i++)
            spaces += " ";
        System.out.println("\t\t" + name[index] + spaces + "$" + sales[index] + "\t\t\t" + "$" + comm[index] + " ");
    }
```

And change the arbitrary 20 to anything you want, eg. the longest string in names + 5.

Comment: One more question please