# How to print an array as a table in Java

Tags: java, arrays, tabular

I have two arrays, one with String and the other one with int:

Create the arrays:

```
// Data //
     /* Marks array*/            static int[] marks = new int[3];
     /* Subject name array*/   static String[] subjects = new String[3];
// Data //
```

Make the user input 3 values into each array:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Input the names of your subjects");
        subjects[i] = scan.next();
        System.out.println("");
    }                
    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Input your marks");
        marks[i] = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Ouput arrays:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(subjects));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(marks));
```

The code works and everything but the output is like this:

```
[Maths, History, French]
[10, 8, 6]
```

I want to make it so it displays like a table independently of the length of the values:

```
[Maths, History, French]
[   10,       8,      6]
```

Comment: I have tried to use JTable but it didn't work well

Comment: [See this Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358512/java-println-formatting-so-i-can-display-a-table) Tell me if you still need help

Comment: JTable is about `Swing`, your example is using the `System.out`. Please see [ask]. I do believe you thought `JTable` would work in the terminal but this is for a GUI.

Comment: I know, i just returned where I was with the `System.out`. Oh.